# unable to display(echo) image even image has been saved to database

Tags: php

/*this code is working(echoing image) on localhost but not displaying on live site   */ 
  PLEASE HELP,,,,

```
 <?php echo "<img src=geti/tipb_geti.php?id=$lastid  width=200px height=180px >";
```

/*this below php block is tipb_geti.php file*/

```
 <?php
      include("connect.php");
      $id=@addslashes($_REQUEST['id']);

      $image_query=@mysql_query("select image from tipuranibasti where id=$id");
        $image_row=@mysql_fetch_assoc($image_query);


            $image=$image_row['image']; 
            header("content-type: image/jpeg");

          echo $image;              

?>
```

Comment: that doesnt look cakephp related at all. the tag can be removed.

Comment: addslashes is a piece of ancient crap and is NOT safe for sql injection prevention. You should remove any knowledge of the function's existence from your brain and switch to mysql_real_escape_string() immediately.

Answer (score 2):

What's the memory limit on your live server? You're making TWO copies of the image data here:

```
$image=$image_row['image'];
```

which is utterly pointless. You could simply have

```
echo $image_row['image'];
```

instead and save yourself the extra wasteful/pointless copy operation.

Answer (score -1):

Check if your characterencodigs. The livedb might have got UTF8 ancoding or the server has, but you not, if not, what is the output? Comment out `header("content-type: image/jpeg");` and check if you get the same things live and local.

oh and i would prefer:

```
<?php print'<img src="geti/tipb_geti.php?id=' . $lastid . '"  width="200px" height="180px" />';
```

makes your html/xhtml a bit more well formatted and `print'test';` is slightly faster than `print"test";` since "$var" will output the content of $var and '$var' wont, this is a little less overheat. But don't think you gain hyperspeed from that :P You won'T notice the bit more performance, I only think it provides a better code.

Comment: i comment out header(from local) but its still printing the image  
i dont understand whts the problem with live..

Comment: try to write both into a file. make sure tu use the same character encoding than compare both files

Comment: i think problem is only in displaying the image..
because it was showing crack image when i click on it.full image sohws up.

Comment: @kerwindena: unless you're running PHP scripts on the level of facebook, the overhead of a `''` string v.s. a `""` string is utterly undetectable.

Comment: @MarcB Sure thats right but I think that improvements should be used, regardless of how much they causes... And I think print''; has got 2 additional advantages: you do not need to escape " wich you should use in (x)html and so on for your tags, second you have to exclude the printig of variables wich makes them easy to find when debugging... (Will be colourd differently when syntaxhighlighting)

Comment: @kerwindena: that's why there's heredocs. they make it very easy to build multi-line strings with no need for escaping quotes.